# Align* environment, equations are right bounded / flushes

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align, environments, amsmath

I'm experiencing some troubles with LaTeX. I really don't understand why the align environment doesn't work properly. I want the equations to be all bounded by the left. What can I do?

[image: notcentered]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
X_t = \{X_t^1,X_t^2\} =\{ ({3/10} t^3 - 6t^2+4t+7)/50,  \log(t+9)\} \\
dX_t^1 = ({9/10} t^2 - 12t+4)/50 dt \\ 
dX_t^2 = 1/ (t+9)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have not specified any alignment point in the align, normally you would use `&=` not `=` on each row. Your lines are flush right as they are all the left hand side of an equation with no right hand side, due to the missing `&`

Comment: @David..... I guess I tried the Sledgehammer to crack a little nut. Thank you. I tried that before, but not on all lines... :/

Comment: ... and `mathtools` already loads `amsmath`, no need to load it twice :)

Comment: @Simona, you receive two answer which solve your question. so, now is time to select the best one and accept it (by clicking check mark at top left side of answers). as i see, so far you not accept any answer on your questions. are they not useful to you?

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
X_t &= \{X_t^1,X_t^2\} =\{ ({3/10} t^3 - 6t^2+4t+7)/50,  \log(t+9)\} \\
dX_t^1 &= ({9/10} t^2 - 12t+4)/50 dt \\ 
dX_t^2 &= 1/ (t+9)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

`align` should always have alignment points specified by `&`, the part before `&` is right aligned, the part after `&` is left aligned.

Answer (score 2):

Also the combination of environments

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned} 
...
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

could do the job. And being a little *squeamish*, I included declaration `\newcommand{\di}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}` in preamble to create ***Differential Operator*** d (just for the pursue typographical accuracy of math format).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\di}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
X_t        & = \{X_t^1,X_t^2\} =\{ ({3/10} t^3 - 6t^2+4t+7)/50,  \log(t+9)\} \\
\di X_t^1  & = ({9/10} t^2 - 12t+4)/50\di t \\ 
\di X_t^2  & = 1/ (t+9)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```